# From the age or ages of fifteen to twenty-one?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, grammatical-number, numbers

Are both examples correct or is there only one way to write it?

> The program is for people from the *age* of fifteen to twenty-one.

OR

> The program is for people from the *ages* of fifteen to twenty-one.

To me *ages* (plural) makes sense because I am talking about more than one age but I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: A more complete example sentence might be helpful.   I'd more likely say "between the ages of..."

Comment: From the age of 15 to 21, or between the ages of 15 and 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, only the singular is possible. A range of ages ("from age 1 to age 2") starts at one age (singular) and ends at another. We can also talk about the period between a pair of ages (plural).

The expression "from **the age of** fifteen to **the age of** twenty-one" can be written without the second occurrence of "from the age of", as in your example.

> During the period from the age of twenty to that of thirty, the
>   mortality was eight per cent.; from thirty to forty, thirteen and one-
>   tenth ; from forty to fifty, thirteen
>
> From the age of twenty to the age of forty, Bessemer lived the life of
>   a journeyman inventor.
>
> The law also imposed penalties on orbi, that is, married persons who
>   had no children (qui liberos non habent, Gaius, ii.111) from the age
>   of twenty-five to sixty in a man, and from the age of twenty to fifty
>   in a woman.
>
> Every Frenchman therefore is a member of the army practically or
>   potentially from the age of twenty to the age of forty-five.
>
> A man from the age of twenty to sixty shall pay twenty-five dollars;
>
> It took me from the age of twenty to twenty six to finally realize I
>   could be a good husband to the woman I loved
>
> Way back in 1908, Kreisler (in an interview) said in the October issue
>   of The Strad 'I am thirty-three now, and from the age of twenty to
>   twenty-seven I struggled
>
> Sunglasses are one of the only pieces in a gentleman's wardrobe that
>   he can have from the age of twenty to sixty without having to change

[Examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBGB748GB748&ei=2BgBW9iJN-Tv5gLAvJzIDg&q=%22from%20the%20age%20of%20twenty%20to%22&oq=%22from%20the%20age%20of%20twenty%20to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20991.24332.0.25219.13.13.0.0.0.0.93.923.13.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.f2rK7pF4Hu4)